# Compilation of Pro*C code on Mac

Tags: oracle, oracle-pro-c

I have modified a code written in Pro*C language but I dont know how to compile it and check if there are any compilation errors. How can I compile the file xyzcode.pc and make an executable file on a Mac system. Please note that I am using a Mac system. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compile Pro*C code under Mac OSX because the Pro*C executable (`proc`) is not available for Mac OSX.

Pro*C is part of the Oracle database, standard/enterprise edition.

Oracle does not provide downloads of Oracle 11g or 12c for Mac OSX.

It seems that it [had provided its 10g version for Mac OSX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/macos/whatsnew/index.html), though - but it is not available anymore.